# SWT Listener with complex generics

Tags: java, generics, events, swt, listener

**SWT version**: 4.4

**Java compiler**: 1.6

I'm trying to implement a listener of mine inheriting from FocusAdapter. The listener is supposed to copy from one control to another and the controls inherit from SWT Control (you can watch the imports) and implement MyControl (a  getValue(), setValue(T val) interface).

The thing is that it doesn't seem to recognise the generic T type and something must be wrong with the syntax but can't find what.

I know that you can declare a generic type with  where SuperType may be parent or interface. As well you can declare more than one supertype with &.

EDITED: I did as Andy suggested. Now the new error about the listener class says:

[image: compilation error]

Please help.
The code is right below. Thanks in advance.

**MyControl.java**

```
public interface MyControl<T> {
    T getValue();

    void setValue(T value);

    void resetValue();
}
```

**CopyOnFocusListener.java**

```
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;

// This was the former, original question
//public class CopyOnFocusListener<C extends Control & MyControl<T>> extends FocusAdapter {

public class CopyOnFocusListener<T, C extends Control & MyControl<T>> extends FocusAdapter {

    private final C fromControl;
    private final C toControl;


    public CopyOnFocusListener(final C fromControl,
            final C toControl) {
        super();
        this.fromControl = fromControl;
        this.toControl = toControl;
        fromControl.addFocusListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void focusLost(final FocusEvent event) {
        final T fromValue = fromControl.getValue();
        toControl.setValue(fromValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare the type variable: `CopyOnFocusListener<T, C extends Control & MyControl<T>>`

Comment: What is `MyControl`. I don't get any error compiling this (guessing at what MyControl is).

Comment: @greg-449 I added the code for MyControl. Is a very simple interface, as I said in the original question, but I think that you're right the code might help

Comment: This still compiles OK for me.

Comment: @greg-449 Strange. Have you used the org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control??? That is the class creating the main issue.

Comment: Where are you actually getting the error? Show us a [mcve] demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @greg-449 I added an image showing where the error does show inside Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why Eclipse is generating that specific message but the issue is that on some platforms `Control` has a package private abstract method - something like:

```
 abstract String windowClass();
```

So `Control` can only be extended by another class in the `org.eclipse.swt.widgets` package.

The generic class you are passing to `CopyOnFocusListener` needs to extend `Control` but also implement your `MyControl` class, I think this is what is upsetting Eclipse.

You might be able to use `Widget` in place of `Control` (Control extends Widget).

I don't get this error message on my system because the macOS version of `Control` doesn't have the `windowClass` method.

Note that many SWT controls make a special check for classes outside of the `org.eclipse.swt.widgets` package trying to extend the class and throw an exception. So you will have trouble adding the `MyControl` interface to these controls.